# How to show an image that is hidden using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues showing an image that is hidden using jQuery.

I have hidden the an image with the class 'img.zoom' using jQuery. I want to be able to hover over the list item that the image is within and show the image that is hidden. I am able to do this but it affects every list item with that image in. I only want it to affect that particular list item.

Please help.

My code:

```
 <ul class="portfolio">
  <li> <img src="images/example.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Example" /> <img src="images/row.png" width="11" height="11" class="zoom" /> </li>
  <li><img src="images/example.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Example" /><img src="images/row.png" width="11" height="11" class="zoom" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/example.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Example" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/example.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Example" /></li>
</ul>
```

my js:

```
// hide zoom button
$("img.zoom").hide(); 
// show zoom button on hover
$("ul li").hover(function () {
$('img.zoom').show();
});
```

Many thanks in advance.

Craig

UPDATE

I have managed to work this out by adjusting the code like so

```
$('img.zoom', this).toggle();
```

But is there away to fadeToggle this in and out?

Comment: You'd be better off asking a new question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in your hover function

```
$(this).find('img.zoom').show();
```

`this` in a callback function represents the current DOM element, so `$(this)` will resolve to a jQuery object representing the hovered `li`, and `find` will do a CSS select based on the descendents of that `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to be complete and take Akira's answer 1 step further

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img.zoom').show();
},function() {
    $(this).find('img.zoom').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the fade:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {  
    $(this).find('img.zoom').fadeIn();  
},function() {  
    $(this).find('img.zoom').fadeOut();  
});
```